# how change destktop environment in kali 2 sana

Tags: kali-linux, desktop-environments

i just installed cinnamon and KDE in Kali 2 but i don't know how to change my Desktop to cinnamon or KDE.

in Kali 1 on the login screen there was this option to change the desktop environment but in Kali 2 it just says enter your password.

Answer (score -1):

Try: apt-get upgrade. The packages are probably in a preparatory state.
It takes about 15 minutes to download and install a Cinnamon environment because I'm doing it right now. I imagine it's no different for other environments.

Comment: Even the latest version of kali2 has this issue.